# Calling a python argparse interface from python without Subprocess

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

Consider **the following toy python application**, which only have argparse CLI argparse interface.

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Printer")
    parser.add_argument("message")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args.message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want to use it **from another python script**,

- without having to refactor the toy example (because it might be laborious, or maybe I do not have permission to modify it)
- without calling a python `Subprocess` (because it breaks the call stack, sometimes break pycharm debugger, and make debugging harder in general).

Any way to achieve this ?

Comment: You can assign the list of arguments you want to parse to `sys.argv` before calling `main()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can manipulate the `sys.argv` list to get your intended behavior.

```py
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Printer")
    parser.add_argument("message")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args.message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]]  # remove original arguments except the path
    sys.argv.append('hello')
    main()
```

```
hello
```

make sure to save `sys.argv.copy()` somewhere to reset it once your function is done.

Comment: thanks, I also found some more details here https://jugmac00.github.io/blog/testing-argparse-applications-the-better-way/